# Fetching messages stored on Python's socketserver.TCPServer via sock.recv() call

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I have the following simplified project structure:

```
tcp-test-project/
|
+-- server.py
+-- client.py
```

`server.py` contains the following:

```py
from socketserver import ThreadingTCPServer, StreamRequestHandler

LOCALHOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8000


class MsgQueueServer:

    def __init__(self,  port):
        self.port = port
        self.msg_q = []

    def start(self):
        print(f"starting MsgQueueServer at {LOCALHOST}:{self.port}")
        with MsgQueueTCPServer((LOCALHOST, self.port), MyMessageHandler, self.msg_q) as server:
            server.serve_forever()


class MsgQueueTCPServer(ThreadingTCPServer):

    def __init__(self, host_port_tup, request_handler, msg_q):
        super().__init__(host_port_tup, request_handler)
        self.msg_q = msg_q


class MyMessageHandler(StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.cmd, self.msg = self.rfile.readline().decode().split(":", maxsplit=1)
        self._get_cmd_handler()()

    def _get_cmd_handler(self):
        return {
            "/NEW": self._recv_message,
            "/GET": self._send_messages,
        }[self.cmd]

    def _recv_message(self):
        self.server.msg_q.append(self.msg)
        print(f"server message queue contains messages: {self.server.msg_q}")

    def _send_messages(self):
        print("sending messages in msg_q to client...")
        for msg in self.server.msg_q:
            self.wfile.write(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = MsgQueueServer(PORT)
    server.start()
```

And `client.py` is:

```py
import socket


class MsgQueueClient:

    def __init__(self, server_addr):
        self.host, port = server_addr.split(":")
        self.port = int(port)

    def send_message(self, message):
        """Send a message to the server."""

        cmd = "/NEW"
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
            sock.send(bytes(f"{cmd}:{message}", "utf-8"))
        print(f"sent message: '{message}' to MsgQueueServer at {self.host}:{self.port}")

    def get_messages(self):
        """Fetch a list of all messages stored by the server."""

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
            sock.send(bytes("/GET:", "utf-8"))

            print("waiting on message from server...")
            received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print(received)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_addr = "127.0.0.1:8000"
    client = MsgQueueClient(server_addr)

    client.send_message("Hello")
    client.send_message("World")

    client.get_messages()
```

Now at a shell prompt with the project root as my CWD, I start the server:

```sh
$ python3 server.py
starting MsgQueueServer at 127.0.0.1:8000
```

In a new shell, I run the client:

```sh
$ python3 client.py
sent message: 'Hello' to MsgQueueServer at 127.0.0.1:8000
sent message: 'World' to MsgQueueServer at 127.0.0.1:8000
waiting on message from server...
```

At this point, if I bring up the stdout of the server process, I see the following:

```sh
$ python3 server.py
starting MsgQueueServer at 127.0.0.1:8000
server message queue contains messages: ['Hello']
server message queue contains messages: ['Hello', 'World']
```

So the logged print statements indicate that two messages sent from the client to the server were successfully received by the server and stored into its `msg_q` property. But when I try to retrieve those stored messages on the server through the call to `sock.recv(1024)` in the client, it blocks and won't proceed with the communication.

I mostly followed the `socketserver.TCPServer` example from Python's docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example). And to be frank, I'm not seeing what I'm missing here that makes my example not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I understand problem - but if client want to `recv` then server has to `send` in the same time. But server will not send automatically. You have to add code which will send it. Usually client-server do: client use `send` and server `recv`, after gettting message server runs `send` and client `recv` - end of single connection.

Comment: `recv` reads from local buffer and other computer doesn't know that it has to send something.

Comment: This is what I'd expect to happen: 1) `client.get_messages()` calls `sock.send()` which sends the command `"/GET"` to the server, 2) the message handler on the server reads the command sent from the client using `self.rfile.readline()`, 3) b/c the sent command is `"/GET"`, the handler calls its `_send_messages` method, which then sends data back to the client using `self.wfile.write`, 4) the client `sock.recv` the messages sent back by the server, 5) socket connection closes.

Comment: When I add a print in the handler's `_get_cmd_handler` function: `print(f"client sent command: {self.cmd}")`, right before the return. Then start the server, followed by the client, I get the following output on the server:

```bash
$ python3 server.py
starting MsgQueueServer at 127.0.0.1:8000
client sent command: /NEW
server message queue contains messages: ['Hello']
client sent command: /NEW
server message queue contains messages: ['Hello', 'World']
```

So looks like the sent `/GET` command never reaches the server, b/c `sock.recv` in client blocks. I just don't understand why.

Comment: you could add more `print()` in server. ie. at the beginning of `handler`, after `readline()` but before `split()`, etc. Maybe some command doesn't work. I would expect that `readline()` needs text with `\n` at the end to work - but client doesn't send `'\n'`

Comment: @furas Holy sh*t, that worked! I added `"\n"` to the line `sock.send(bytes("/GET:\n", "utf-8"))`, and now I get a response back from the server on my client. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: i also tested `\n` and I realized that after sending `/NEW` it closes connection and server new that it is end of message - and it read it - but normally it need `\n` at the end of every message to read it.

Comment: In hindsight that does make sense. This is what I get for thinking it'd be easier to work with the file/IOStream API, instead of raw `send` and `recv` calls. And my ignorance just end up biting me in the ass.